# A general question about vectors and dot product in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to understand dot product and why it was invented,
I mean why do we need to take two vectors and produce a number and what is that number? and I would be happy to understand this formula better $|v_1||v_2|cos(\theta)$ because for me it make no sense.. ..if I think about it any formula that I met in my life I did not really understand how it works for any specific purpose and what multiplying two different vector length look like if I would like to visualize it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try to search dot product and work in physics. That is a great and intuitive way of understanding why dot product is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice write-up on the dot product http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/DotProduct.aspx. Theorem 2 is particularly useful and gives details behind the geometry of the dot product.